# SQl to Linq query- subquery with datetime

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

I would like to know the LINQ for this SQL.Appreciate any help

```
select Value  FROM GPUD where param ='RVOUTc' 
and   dateandtime in (select  max(b.dateandtime)  from GPUD as b where b.param= 'rvoutc'and convert(date,getdate()) = convert(date,b.DateAndTime) 
group by b.param )
```

Answer (score 0):

Did not test it, but it should get you started, good luck.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var GPUDCollection = new List<GPUD>();

        var maxDate = GPUDCollection.
            Max(gpud => gpud.dateandtime.Date);

        var result = GPUDCollection.
            Where(gpud => gpud.Param.Equals("rvoutc") && gpud.dateandtime.Date.Equals(maxDate)).
            Select(gpud => gpud.Value);
    }
}

public class GPUD
{
    public DateTime dateandtime { get; set; }

    public string Param { get; set; }

    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```